# Applying dynamic filter to a subset of visuals in QuickSight automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, visualization, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

I am building my dashboard using AWS QuickSight. This dashboard contains 8 filters and I need to apply a Dynamic filter using the date as parameter on only a subset of visuals (only 4 of them). For the remaining visuals (means the 4 remaining visuals), I am going to use another date as a filter.

Briefly, the two filters are date 1 and date 2 where the date 1 filters only 4 visuals and the date 2 filters the remaining visuals.
Is there any way to make it automatically? because the unique solution was using the custom action assign one filter to table 1 for example and then associate the table 1 with the remaining visuals (table 2, figure 1 and figure 2).

Another problem was that after selecting the date 1, I need to click on table 1 so the filter is going to be applied to table 2, figure 1 and figure 2. I want to avoid this and after selecting the date 1 is going to be automatically applied to table 1 , table 2 and figure 1 and figure 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Quicksight filters, there is an option to apply the filter for selected visuals and tables (you can choose which visuals or tables you want to apply filters). You can put multiple filters for multiple tables/visuals and add it to the sheet so that you can change from the sheet

[Quicksight filter options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OW2KG.png)

Comment: the problem in that filter is that if I need to deploy it for subset of visuals so each time I need to click on the table containing that filter so I can filter the other visuals

Comment: It is not automatic that when I select the data, for example, all the other visuals are going to change.

Comment: Okay, If I am understanding your problem correctly, this might be the solution- There is this option of adding a filter to the sheet( filter section 3 dots dropdown). When you add the filter to the sheet you can change the filter on the sheet you don't have to go through the hassle of going to the visual each time.

Comment: It is working now thank you for your response